# Spread sheet (like Microsoft Excel) viewer as a service in company LAN

Tags: excel, browser, frameworks, spreadsheet, viewer

Is there framework/ready-to-use system, that will let open *.xls, *.xlsx files in a browser.

For example `http://officeviewer.company.com/file.xls`

For desktop there is free Excell Viewer from Microsoft.
There is also Microsoft cloud service (skydrive.com) that let's open/edit Excel files in a browser.
Not to mention SharePoint.

But we would like that those files do not leave company LAN.
The best case would be
`http://officeviewer.company.com/view?URL=http://wiki.company.com/file.xls`

Free, open-source preferably.

Comment: I am also looking for same thing. Have you found it anywhere?

Comment: Not yet. I would add an answer.